I am trying to retrieve a list of values from the xpath locator RPA selenium the program returns an empty, I can't figure it out
from RPA.Browser.Selenium import Selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



browser = Selenium()

class RPA_Challenge():
    
    def find_search(self):
         # Navigate to url
        browser.open_available_browser("https://news.yahoo.com/")
        #attribute selection(choose element on the html or xml based on their attribute value)
        getElement = browser.find_elements(locator="xpath://input[@name='text']//parent::form")

        # error the returns empty list

        for data in getElement:
            result = data.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'text')
            for input_data in result:
                print(input_data.text)
                time.sleep(4)

I tried to iterate over the getElement variable thats points to the xpath to retrieve the elements of the search

It's returning empty because there's no element on the page that matches the XPath //input[@name='text']//parent::form. What element are you trying to find? There's not even an //input[@name='text']. I think you have the wrong page or the completely wrong locator(s).

oh yeah thanks you actually correct because the program is trying to get an element from the input element tag it return an empty list.
